# How do I "understand" kaomoji? (Japanese smilies)

Tags: usage, meaning, slang, culture, internet-slang

When I see something like this:

```
ﾍ(´∀｀ﾍ)ﾍ(´∀｀ﾍ)ﾖｲﾖｲ(ﾉ´∀｀)ﾉ(ﾉ´∀｀)ﾉﾖｲﾖｲ♪
```

I think some voodoo demon wants to say something to me. o_O

My Japanese friends often use kaomoji.  But, when they add (´▽｀) or (ﾟ∀ﾟ) I can't tell if they are sad, confused, happy, or even angry.  I just can't see the emotion for an upside-down A.

Maybe you can draw something based on the most popular kaomoji, so I can envision it in my mind like you do.

I'm afraid of those demon smilies! Please help me understand how to interpret kaomoji.

Comment: notice that they sometimes have words attached, like the one in your example.

Comment: While accepting questions about "what is kaomoji: ( ・_・)ノ", etc should probably closed under "too localized", I'm pretty sure what the OP was asking for is basically this link: http://www.japaneseemoticons.net/all-japanese-emoticons/ . Note that each category is given a short introduction giving general strategies for interpreting particular emotions.

Comment: What was the defining reason for reopening this question? Is there an answer that relates to the Japanese language more so than addressing just the imagination?

Comment: @Chris See http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/883/arent-kaomoji-part-of-the-japanese-language - or in summary, five people thought it was on-topic and rejected the first close reason.  If the question is too vague, then the "not constructive" reason should have been used instead, but that is a separate argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps [this site](http://www.japaneseemoticons.net/all-japanese-emoticons/) may be of use to you.

For each section there is a brief description and explanation of the choice of symbols/characters used.

The characters used for kaomoji may represent:

- Eyes (usually obvious)(may be covered by arms/hand)
- Ears (may be absent)
- Nose (may be absent)
- Mouth ( `∀` and `▽` in your examples are mouths)
- Limits of the face (usually these - `(` `)` are face delimiters)
- Flushing of cheeks ( may be (but not limited to) `#` or `@` )
- Sweat (usually obvious if present)
- Tears (usually obvious if present)
- Arms/hand  ( `ﾍ` in your example)(And sometimes may be used to cover the eyes)
- Lines of motion ( In `(-_-)ゞ゛`, `ゞ゛` is an arm with lines of motion showing a head-scratching action)
- Objects (占 - spray bottle, 尸 - flag, φ - pen, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

> Please help me with my imagination!

Well, use it. You know that a kaomoji is a face, and I'm adding that it often has arms. Try to see if something looks like a smile, a grin, or whatever… It just takes practice, there is no rule.