# What does ; ; mean?

Tags: meaning, symbols

I exchanged messages recently with someone I met from Japan, and I noticed that he often uses ; ; during our conversation. I assumed it was some kind of emoji but I’m not sure what it is. I tried looking for answers in Google but didn’t find anything. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I "understand" kaomoji? (Japanese smilies)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6119/how-do-i-understand-kaomoji-japanese-smilies)

Answer (score 3):

This may be difficult to search, but this is a type of Japanese "smiley" (or 顔文字) for a face with tears. Imagine something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The longer version is `(;;)` or `(;_;)` representing a face with two eyes and two teardrops with or without lips, or simply a crying face. The parentheses represent the outline of a face but can be omitted in especially casual text messages.

Similarly `(^^)` -- "face with smiling eyes" -- can be shortened `^^`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaomoji

> The emphasis on the eyes in this style is reflected in the common usage of emoticons that use only the eyes, e.g. ^^

Semicolons in general are rarely used in Japanese. I think the most likely place you encounter them used as, well, semilocons, would be text translated from a European language into Japanese. Even then translators may choose to omit ot replace them rather than preserving them.